# Unable to create Aws java web project

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, hibernate, maven

I am new bie to amazon webservices and I am trying to create aws java web project and it is showing an error that,

```
Unable to create new AWS Java web project.
Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:1.0 from any of the 
configured repositories.
Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0 from 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be 
 reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: 
Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0 from/to 
central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0 from 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be 
 reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: 
 Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0 from/to 
 central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
```

Any one please answer soon why I am getting this maven archetype exception,what I need to do.And also is there any tutorial for creating java web applications in aws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

closing the eclipse,Deleting the .m2 repository and opening eclipse has resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

***"And also is there any tutorial for creating java web applications in aws."***

To learn how to create a Java web application using Spring that invokes AWS Services, I recommend that you read this document:

[Creating your first AWS Java web application](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_first_project)

PS - i see your maven issues is resolved- but I will keep this link for other ppl reading this thread.

Comment: I have created a sample web application.To deploy it in elastic bean stalk,I am not getting that page.It is showing as if I have sign up just now for aws.It is asking to add billing account,will they charge for sample application also?

Comment: It is showing that 10000 rupees will be automatically charged from the account. after the month.

Comment: The doc to review for using the Free Tier for AWS Services is https://aws.amazon.com/free/?all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Types=tier%2312monthsfree

Comment: How to check whether my account is free tier or costly?

Comment: That is addressed in this doc here. Look at the Billing and Cost Management console as explained here -- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/free-tier-eligibility.html

Comment: I got to know that until we use free tier level components,The amount will not be charged.Am i right?

Comment: To be 100% sure about Free Tier usage - i recommend reaching out to AWS Support here -- https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/